# A class that extends both Activity and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have tabhost and if I click on any of of them , a new class and its corresponding xml will launch. Each one class extends Activity, but I also need each of them to extends BroadcastReceiver. Why? right now the wordings of each activity and its view text are in English. But in the picker, if someone choose Spanish then I need to broadcast the Intent of setting Spanish to Num1 , Num2, Num3 class and its views that their wordings to be changed to spanish.    Can I have public class Num1 extends Activity, BroadcastReiver, ...etc like that?

```
 host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Num1")
            .setIndicator("Num1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_light))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Num1.class)));

       host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Num2")
            .setIndicator("Num2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_wrench))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Num2.class)));

       host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Num3")
            .setIndicator("Num3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_user))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Num3.class)));
```

Comment: No, a Java class may extend only a single base class.

Comment: You must have some form of mechanism to accomplish the need of multiple inheritance like *interfaces*. Otherwise, Java doesn't directly support the concept of inheriting more than one class together for a single class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot extend two classes. The usual way to deal with this is to define an inner class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private mBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        . . .
        mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            // your receiver implementation
        };
        // register the receiver
    }
    . . .
}
```

In this code the inner class is an anonymous subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`. You can also create a separate class that is passed an instance of your activity in the constructor. It can then make call-backs to your activity as needed.

Comment: Can you give small example of broadcast an intent with message of setting==Spanish or English and then the processing that global broadcast by the receiver?

Comment: @lilzz - After thinking more about what you are trying to accomplish, I think that using a broadcast receiver is overkill. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you are trying to do all this within a single application. It would be far easier to store the current language setting as a shared preference and then each activity could either check the preference setting in `onResume` or else register itself as an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. See [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for more info.